# How to print a letter at a specific index of a string that is in an array in C#?

Tags: c#, console-application

I have been trying to do an effect where the console types out each letter of a string array element one at a time with a slight delay in between. I cannot for the life of me figure out how to print a letter at a specific index of a string in an array (or if its even possible).

I have been trying to do this by using a for loop, increasing the index by 1 everytime it writes the full element and then goes onto the next. The problem is how to print each letter individually. Right now, it just prints the whole string element and then goes to the next and so on. I want it to print each letter individually and then increase the element index.

I have been researching this for hours but cant seem to find anything.

```
public string[] menuInputs = { };

    public void TextAnimateScrollLeft()
    {
        menuInputs = File.ReadAllLines("../MenuInputs.txt");
        menuInputs.Reverse();

        int arrayIndex;
        for(arrayIndex = 0; arrayIndex <= menuInputs.Length - 1; arrayIndex++)
        {
            Console.Write(menuInputs[arrayIndex]);
            Thread.Sleep(50);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: In c#, a string is also a collection of chars. You can iterate and also index them, like mystr[0]

Comment: It just prints the entire string because that's what you told it to do. If you want to print them one at a time with a delay, then you need to loop over each character of the string (a string is just a character array). You need a nested loop inside your existing for loop.

Comment: Perhaps using a `foreach` loop will make things easier to understand: `foreach (string line in menuInputs) { foreach (char c in line) { Console.Write(c.ToString()); Thread.Sleep(50); } }`. See: https://dotnetfiddle.net/gPvoi0. That said, you _can_ still do it with a `for` loop: `for (int charIndex = 0; charIndex < menuInput[arrayIndex].Length; charIndex++) { Console.Write((menuInputs[arrayIndex][charIndex]).ToString()); Thread.Sleep(50); }`.

Comment: You are reading all lines which gives an array of lines. If you want text use readalltext

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Notes are included as comments:

```
//it's not clear just from the ScrollLeft name: 
// do you also want to scroll each string backwards?
// If so, you'll need to make use of the `SetPosition()` function
public void TextAnimateScrollLeft()
{
    var menuInputs = File.ReadAllLines("../MenuInputs.txt");

    //save the work reversing the array by iterating backwards
    for(int arrayIndex = menuInputs.Length -1; arrayIndex >= 0; arrayIndex--)
    {
       // also loop through the characters in each string
       foreach(char c in menuInputs[arrayIndex])
       {
           Console.Write(c);
           Thread.Sleep(50); // 20 characters per second is still pretty fast
       }
       Console.WriteLine(); //don't forget the line break
    } 

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```